# Checking Existence of a Surjective Continuous Map between Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, circles

I am studying topology and recently tried to solve these two questions concerning the existence of a surjective continuous map between spaces. But I am not sure how to construct one, or to claim that there is no such surjective continuous map. The questions(in the form of T/F question) are as follows:

1. There exists a surjective continuous map from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ where $S^2$ is the unit sphere $S^2 := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.$
2. There exists  a surjective continuous map from $S^1$ to $S^1 \times S^1$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle $S^1 := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2=1\}.$

From what I think, I am guessing question 2 is False. (One of my friend told me it seems false due to topological group... But as I did not learn the concept of topological group, I felt there should be some other way to solve this.) That is, there is no surjective continuous map between spaces. But overall, I am not sure whether these statements are true or not. Also, I am not sure of a way to construct a surjective continuous map for them.

Is there some method or way of constructing surjective continuous map in this kind of situations? (Or some criteria that can tell whether these kinds of map exist or not.)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about Peano curves? Do you know if the image of a compact space under a continuous map is again compact?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't know about Peano curves yet, but I do know the part about continuous map preserving compactness. Is that theorem used in this? It seems to be sth about space-filling curve hm.. Maybe that's why I can't solve it yet.. I am right now just studying connected space in Munkre..

Comment: With your current knowledge you can answer Question 1 but not Question 2.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh, is it sth like since unit sphere is compact but R^2 is not a compact space, it is false?

Comment: I suggest you write a carefully written solution of the first problem and post it as a self-answer. As for the 2nd problem, wait until you learn about space-filling curves.

Answer (score 2):

Self-Answer for question 1:

*Proof.* (We will assume $\mathbb{R}$ is given the usual standard topology and the products of the real line is also given the usual product topology.)

Then $S^2$ is compact. This is due to Heine-Borel Thm. $S^2$ is clearly bounded as it is just a unit sphere. It is also closed as it is preimage of closed set {1} of a continuous map $f$ that maps $(x,y,z) \mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2$. (Since multiplication and addition operator preserves the continuity of the functions, this function is continuous.)

Then by Heine-Borel, $S^2$ is compact. Now image of a compact space under continuous function $f$ must be compact. Since the map mentioned above is surjective and continuous, this means $R^2$ must be compact. But $R^n$ is not compact. (By Heine-Borel, we can see that $R^n$ is not bounded or closed.) Thus this is contradiction.

Hence, there can be no such surjective continuous function.

Comment: Good job!......

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you!